# converting python loop to javascript loop

Tags: javascript, python, json

```
stations = {}
stations['kone'] =  set(['id', 'nv', 'ut'])
states_needed = new Set(['mt', 'wa', 'o', 'id', 'nv', 'ut', 'ca', 'az'])

while states_needed:
  best_station = None
  states_covered = set()
  for station, states in stations.items():
    states_needed & states
```

I am trying to translate the above code into javascript. I am getting this error:  'states.has is not a function'. Not sure what I an doing wrong.

```
   stations = {}
   stations['kone'] =  new Set(['id', 'nv', 'ut'])
   states_needed = new Set(['mt', 'wa', 'o', 'id', 'nv', 'ut', 'ca', 'az'])

   while(states_needed){
   let best_station = null
   let states_covered = new Set()
   for(states in Object.entries(stations)){
      new Set(
       [...states_needed].filter(x => states.has(x)))
  }
```

Comment: What is the code trying to do ?

Comment: `states` is an array which looks like this: `["kone", <set>]`. Not sure what you're trying to do with `while(states_needed)`, but something like this might work: `[...states_needed].filter(x => states[1].has(x))`